# Best way to maintain flow of fluid under head?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, valves

[image]

I have a crucible with molten metal flowing under its own head. As per torricelli's law the velocity of the fluid would be $\sqrt{2gh}$.

Is there any mechanism with which I can maintain a constant flow rate of my choice?

Comment: I don't know much about the fluid properties of molten metals, but note that Toricelli's Law assumes an inviscid fluid.  Water is fairly close to inviscid for common applications of Toricellis - metal may not be.  ... For water, the way to maintain a constant flow rate would be to maintain a constant head, either by replacement, or by having a large enough US reservoir that loss through flow doesn't matter.  Again, I don't know if those are practical solutions to your molten metal quandary.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain flow rate (Q), velocity (v) must be constant. To keep velocity constant, potential head(h) must be constant. To keep potential head constant either a large crucible (like a reservoir) can be used OR flow rate OUT of crucible must be equal to flow rate IN to the crucible.